# Binding event to all html elements with data-info-modal set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to have something like this:

```
<span data-info-modal="some-value"></span>
```

1) Each element with `data-info-modal` should fire some event on user `click`. 
2) On user click, I need to get value from `data-info-modal` (in the example, it would be `some-value`). This value is some key to get `description`.
3) Using the `description` I have, I need to open a modal window.

Basically, I have to add an event to each element that has `data-info-modal` set. The event would fire function:

```
function myfunction() {
   var getSomeValue = //get some value from data-info-modal
   var getDescription = getDescription(getSomeValue);
   $('desc-modal').show();
};
```

I do not know how to add this event and how to get `some-value` from `data-info-modal`. I do not know how to call this (data part) properly, so I could not find anything helpful via search engine.

Comment: What you call the "data part" are custom data *attributes*, and you can select elements based on data attributes in the same way you can select elements based on other attributes. I hope that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind event using [Has Attribute Selector [name]](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.

then you can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to fetch value, as identifier is with multiple words, need to use camelCase notation

```
$("[data-info-modal]").on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).data('infoModal'))
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-info-modal]").on('click', function(_) {
    alert($(this).data('infoModal'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-info-modal="some-value">example</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like following

```
$('span[data-info-modal]').on('click', function () {
    //....
});
```